# Is fumufumu the same as soudesu?

Tags: colloquial-language

I am unable to find an explanation of the 2 distinct terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "words" are not synonyms although they both can be used as [aizuchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aizuchi).

`ふむふむ` is onomatopoeia for the sound of agreement (similar to English *Uh-huh*).

`そうです` literally means "It is so" and can be used both for agreeing with the other party and as an analog of "I see" (invitation to continue the conversation but without a specific expression of agreement with what's being said).